Configuration load error upon restarting the AppService
Since last week I am experiencing the following issue - App Service gets restarted and it fails to start with the following error:

InvalidDataException: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\home\site\diagnostics\settings.json'.

Inner exceptions are FormatException:

JsonReaderException: The input does not contain any JSON tokens.
and Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

This file is outside of application scope and it contains valid JSON when I review it.
{ "AzureDriveEnabled" : true, "AzureDriveTraceLevel" : "Information" }

Stacktrace of the code which is trying to access it:
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(bool reload)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList<IConfigurationProvider> providers)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices.SiteConfigurationProvider.GetAzureLoggingConfiguration(IWebAppContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServicesLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(ILoggingBuilder builder, IWebAppContext context, Action<AzureBlobLoggerOptions> configureBlobLoggerOptions)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServicesLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(ILoggingBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.AppServicesWebHostBuilderExtensions+<>c.<UseAzureAppServices>b__0_0(ILoggingBuilder builder)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action<ILoggingBuilder> configure)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ConfigureLogging>b__0(IServiceCollection collection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingStartupWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ConfigureServices>b__0(WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
System.Action<T1, T2>.Invoke(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<.ctor>b__6_2(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.BootstrapHostBuilder.RunDefaultCallbacks(ConfigurationManager configuration, HostBuilder innerBuilder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder..ctor(WebApplicationOptions options, Action<IHostBuilder> configureDefaults)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(string[] args)
*******.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs

AppService is running on .NET6 and the issue disappears after 2-3 restarts.
Redeploying the application did not solve the issue.
Update:
Issue has persisted after .NET8 upgrade.

Please share your settings.json file.

@Harshitha I have added the file content.

Are you getting the error in local as well?

This issues is Azure only - to be more specific it is occurring only on single App Service.
I have 2 additional environments (dev, test) with identical setup and they are not experiencing this issue. Issue has occurred even after scaling up the ASP.

@lijevosmetalo try upgrading your .Net version in Azure app service.

@SirraSneha I have updated it to .NET 8 in meantime and issues has occurred again.

The error you're encountering occurs when the configuration file is temporarily inaccessible or is being read before it’s fully available. It might be due to slow loading during restarts.

The issue typically resolves after a few restarts, we can use the Polly library to define a retry policy.
Refer this doc for better understanding about polly library.
This will make sure that if the file isn't available immediately, the application will keep trying to load it, which lowers the chance of startup failure.

Added the below lines in program.cs file

When loading configuration files, if an exception occurs, Polly will retry the operation up to three times. This prevents the error.

var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
    (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
    {
        logger.LogError($"Retrying configuration load due to error: {exception.Message}");
    });

My program.cs file:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Polly;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
});

var logger = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
    (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
    {
        logger.LogError($"Retrying configuration load due to error: {exception.Message}");
    });
retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
{   
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);   
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Make sure you enable Always on in configuration section of your Azure App Service. This will warm up the app before it starts accepting requests.

Output after deployment without any issues.


If possible I would suggest to use Polly V8 instead of Polly V7. Latter is already in maintenance mode.

Thanks for the suggestion, but how can I use Polly when the error occurs on this line
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); ?
It fails to read the file outside of the application scope.
Application is set to "Always on" mode.
The issue still happens once or twice a week.
